# Ist „unhäufig“ ein Neologismus?

Tags: word-usage, neologism

Weder im online Duden noch auf Wiktionary gibt es einen Treffer zu *unhäufig*. Ist dieses Wort nun ein Neologismus? Ich denke die Bedeutung ist in diesem Fall klar: *unhäufig* entspricht *selten*.

Comment: Wo hast Du das Wort denn gesehen oder gehört?

Comment: @CarstenS Ich habe es einfach gesagt...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ergänzend zu [C.p.’s Ngram](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/30413) kann ich nur dem Kommentar von [Tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30411/ist-unh%c3%a4ufig-ein-neologismus#comment74308_30413) zustimmen:

> Sieht auch »überhaupt nicht nach Wort aus«.

Zur Untermauerung und zum Vergleich das [Ngram von *unhäufig* und *rar*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unh%C3%A4ufig%2Crar&year_start=1860&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunh%C3%A4ufig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crar%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cunh%C3%A4ufig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crar%3B%2Cc1):

[image: Google Ngram von *unhäufig* und *rar*]

Und nur um das noch einmal ins Verhältnis zu setzen, das [Ngram von *unhäufig*, *rar* und *selten*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unh%C3%A4ufig%2Crar%2C+selten&year_start=1860&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunh%C3%A4ufig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cselten%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Google Ngram von *unhäufig*, *rar* und *selten*]

Es wäre besser als [Okkasionalismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelegenheitsbildung) beschrieben.

Comment: Man sieht es also unhäufig :-)

Answer (score 4):

Als Münchner ist mir das 'unhäufig' geläufig. Ich kenne es aber in erster Linie  in Zusammenhang mit 'nicht'. Nicht unhäufig bedeutet gar nicht mal so selten, aber auch nicht häufig.
Im Bairischen neigt man zur Sprachfaulheit, hat aber auch Freude an Verschleierungen. 
Bei 'Gar nie nicht' muss man auch überlegen. Ist 'überhaupt nicht' oder 'eben schon' gemeint.

Comment: Das würde sich demnach zu Ausdrücken gesellen wie "nicht unübel" oder "nicht undumm", mit denen man Gesprächspartner verwirren kann.

Comment: Dann wäre es ein Regionalismus. Die grundsätzliche Frage wäre für mich, wann man überhaupt von einem Neologismus sprechen kann. Als Neologismus werden meist Wörter und Redeweisen bezeichnet, die einem als neu und ungewöhnlich vorkommen, bevor sie sich dann, je nach Popularität, im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch einbürgern. Als Nicht-mehr-Neologismus empfinde ich 'alles gut' in der Bedeutung 'mach dir deswegen keine  Gedanken';  ebenso 'Selfie'. Neuer, aber auch nicht mehr taufrisch wäre 'chill mal deine Base/Basis'. 'Aus Gründen' für eine Antwortverweigerung auf 'warum?' könnte echt neo sein.

Answer (score 2):

*unhäufig* sieht [nicht](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unh%C3%A4ufig&year_start=1860&year_end=2014&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunh%C3%A4ufig%3B%2Cc0) nach Neologismus aus:

[image]

Comment: Sieht auch "überhaupt nicht nach Wort aus" - Mit den vorhandenen Antonymen zu *häufig* wie "rar"; "selten", "vereinzelt",.... ist es auch ziemlich unnötig.

Comment: @tofro Ich glaube, das ist für Freunde mehrfacher Negative, z.B. *das Wort liest man heute gar nicht mal zu unhäufig*.